# How to reshape dataframe in order to get the desired output in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this format.

I have this dataframe:

```
   id    2005-01-07   2008-01-07    ...
0  1Y           1.0          1.6
1  5Y           1.0          1.7
2  6Y           6.0          1.0
3  10Y          2.0          7.1
4  30Y          5.5          8.6
```

And I would like to convert it in:

```
   id           Date     number
0  1Y     2005-01-07        1.0
1  1Y     2008-01-07        1.6
2  5Y     2005-01-07        1.0
3  5Y     2008-01-07        1.7
4  6Y     2005-01-07        6.0
5  6Y     2008-01-07        1.0
6  10Y    2005-01-07        2.0
7  10Y    2008-01-07        7.1
8  30Y    2005-01-07        5.5
9  30Y    2008-01-07        8.6
...
```

Is it possible to achieve this output in python? I tried to use `transpose()`  and `replace`  but can't reach the desired output

Answer by @mechanical_meat:

`df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], var_name='Date', value_name='number')`

Comment: this is a `melt` re-shape @Scott Boston  not pivot

Comment: @Datanovice exactly, that was the answer "mechanical_meat" gave. And that function is not addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: @mechanical_meat: it would help in your answer to explain why this particular case you use `pd.melt` rather than `pd.pivot`

Comment: @smci: you're right. I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) we can go **from wide- to long-form** in one easy step:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'], var_name='Date', value_name='number')
```

**The reason `.melt()` is of particular use here is that you're *unpivoting* instead of pivoting**:

- In other words, the remaining columns not identified in `id_vars` keyword argument are then *unpivoted* into rows.

---

If you ever need to go back to the original format you can then use `.pivot()`:

```
df.pivot(values='number',index='id',columns='Date')
```